# Observing ember store from component

Tags: ember.js

*Warning contains legacy code*

I have a component that receives a model containing the majority of the data that belongs to it. However, the component has a component within it that is using global settings from the store to display data.

A user request has been made so that if changes are made to the model then it also updates the global settings store, which then updates the internal component.

I have updated ember so that it updates the store, but how can I put an observer on the store for the internal component?

I have tried the following for the internal component, but it never makes it to the observer function:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  store: Ember.inject.service(),
  globals: Ember.computed('store', function() {
    return this.get('store').peekRecord('globals', 0);
  }),
  globalObserver: Ember.observer('globals', function() {
    console.log("Hello World");
  }
});
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  store: Ember.inject.service(),
  globals: Ember.computed(function() {
    return this.get('store').findRecord('globals',0);
  }),      
  globalObserver: Ember.observer('globals', function() {
    console.log("Hello World");
  }
});
```

Comment: i have n't done this before. may be give it a shot..if it's not working i will remove my answer..may be you can even try with `Ember.observer('globals.propertyname'` ..

Comment: I tried both of these methods, and neither of them seem to work. Thanks for trying though.